# Kafka messages are stored in cluster/ensemble but aren't retrieved by consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have a 2 server zookeeper+Kafka setup with the following config duplicated over the two servers:

## Kafka config

```
broker.id=1 #2 for the second server 
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://server1_ip:9092
zookeeper.connect=server1_ip:2181,server2_ip:2181
num.partitions=3
offsets.topic.replication.factor=2 #how many servers should every topic be replicated to
```

## zookeeper config

```
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
maxClientCnxns=200
admin.enableServer=false
server.1=server1_ip:2888:3888
server.2=server2_ip:2888:3888
initLimit=20
syncLimit=10
```

Successfully created a topic using:

```
/usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper server1_ip:2181,server2_ip:2181 --replication-factor 2 --partitions 3 --topic replicatedtest
```

Doing a Describe on topic using:

```
/usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server=server1_ip:2181,server2_ip:2181 --describe --topic replicatedtest
```

shows the following:

```
Topic: replicatedtest   PartitionCount: 3   ReplicationFactor: 2    Configs: segment.bytes=1073741824
    Topic: replicatedtest   Partition: 0    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,1   Isr: 2,1
    Topic: replicatedtest   Partition: 1    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1,2   Isr: 1,2
    Topic: replicatedtest   Partition: 2    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,1   Isr: 2,1
```

At this point everything looks good. However when I push messages using the following:

```
/usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list server1_ip:9092,server2_ip:9092 --topic replicatedtest
>Hello
>Hi
```

and call the consumer script using:

```
/usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server server1_ip:9092,server2_ip:9092 --topic replicatedtest --from-beginning
```

The consumer just stalls.

When I check if these messages exist via an admin UI (KafkaMagic) they do come up. So looks like the messages are stored successfully but for some reason the consumer script can't get to them.

Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance!

==Edit==
added a 3rd server. Changed log level to TRACE in tools-log4j.properties and this is what the consumer script outputs:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/12nfML7M2a5QyXQswIZ_QVGuNqkc2DTRLPKqvRfDWKDY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Some corrections,

1. `offsets.topic.replication.factor` does not set default replication factor for the created topics, it is for the internal __offset topic that keeps your offsets of the consumer group
2. I have never heard or seen a setup with 2 zookeepers, the recommended is odd number where 1 / 3 or 5 at maximum , where usually 3 is more then enough.
3. for brokers as well the recommended setup is at least 3 replicas with minimum in sync replica of 2

For further assistance please provide the logs of the server / set consumer at debug / issue consumer-groups describe / issue the console consumer with --group test1 for easier investigation

Update: according to your provided docs

The group coordinator is not available

"
I faced a similar issue. The problem was when you start your Kafka broker there is a property associated with the offset topic replication factor which it default to 3
"

Can you do topic --list and make sure `__consumer_offsets` topic exists?

If not please create it and restart brokers/zookeeprs and try consume again

kafka-topics --bootstrap-server node1:9092  --partitions 50 --replication-factor 3 --create --topic __consumer_offsets

Comment: Corrected the offsets.topic setting. Added 3rd server as suggested but the problem persists. I've provided consumer log output in the updated question body .. Thanks!

Comment: Posted and update please check if __consumer_offsets exists in your deployment

Comment: yeah __consumer_offsets exist, but when I do a describe on topic, consumer_offsets seem to be without a leader, so I get something like: Leader: None, Replicas: 0 ... I ended  up deleting /tmp/kafka-logs and /tmp/zookeeper/version-2 then reset the consumer_offeset topic.. I am giving details in my answer. Thanks so much for your help. Wouldn't have found it w/out your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like issue happened because I started off with one node and then decided to move to a cluster/ensemble setup that includes the original node. __consumer_offsets apparently needed to be reset in this case. This is what I ended up doing to solve issue:

stop zookeeper and kafka on all 3 servers

```
systemctl stop kafka
systemctl stop zookeeper
```

delete existing topic data

```
rm -rf /tmp/kafka-logs
rm -rf /tmp/zookeeper/version-2
```

delete __consumer_offsets (calling the same delete command on each zookeeper instance might not be necessary)

```
/usr/local/kafka/bin/zookeeper-shell.sh server1_ip:2181 <<< "deleteall /brokers/topics/__consumer_offsets"
/usr/local/kafka/bin/zookeeper-shell.sh server2_ip:2181 <<< "deleteall /brokers/topics/__consumer_offsets"
/usr/local/kafka/bin/zookeeper-shell.sh server3_ip:2181 <<< "deleteall /brokers/topics/__consumer_offsets"
```

restart servers

```
systemctl start zookeeper
systemctl start kafka
```

recreate __consumer_offsets

```
/usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper server1_ip:2181,server2_ip:2181,server3_ip:2181 --create --topic __consumer_offsets --partitions 50  --replication-factor 3
```

Solution was based off: https://community.microstrategy.com/s/article/Kafka-cluster-health-check-fails-with-the-error-Group-coordinator-lookup-failed-The-coordinator-is-not-available?language=en_US